# Offset clear adjacent cells option

Tags: excel, vba

I did a post yesterday asking how to clear adjacent dropdown lists when parent list changes. I was able to find a post, adjust my code, and get it to work.

Now the issue I'm facing is that I need it to be optional:

- If the column 1 changes, then clear offset column B & C cells.
- If the change is selected in column 2, then only clear offset column C cell.

Below is my code so far - it works when making the change in column A, but I need it be optional if I only make the change in column B, and clear the adjacent cell in column C.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Target.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub   'screen out multi-cell changes
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub 'col2 only
    If Not CellHasValidation(Target) Then Exit Sub '...with validation
    
    On Error GoTo haveError 'ensure events are not left off
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
    Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = ""
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    Target.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
    
haveError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

```
'check if a cell has validation
Function CellHasValidation(cell As Range) As Boolean
    Dim vt
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore if error (no validation)
    vt = cell.Validation.Type
    On Error GoTo 0 'stop ignoring errors
    CellHasValidation = Not IsEmpty(vt)
End Function
```

Comment: Not everyone likes volatility; however, depending on how you generate your combobox data, you may be able to use `indirect(namedRange)` to have the second and third combobox be dependent on the previous inputs.  E.g., Combobox1 = Cat, Combobox2 options are "meow, coax" and if Combobox2 = Dog, Combobox2 options are "bark, pant".

Comment: @Cyril: I am not using comboboxes, so this would not effectively work. However, Tim's solution below works fully for what I was needing. Thanks!

Comment: A dropdown is a combobox in regard to your question.  Alas, I am glad Tim could help you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    If Target.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub  'screen out multi-cell changes
    
    If Target.Column > 2 Then Exit Sub 'col 1/2
    
    If Not CellHasValidation(Target) Then Exit Sub '...with validation
    
    On Error GoTo haveError 'ensure events are not left off
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'loop to max column to be cleared
    For i = Target.Column + 1 To 3
        With Target.EntireRow.Cells(i)
            .Value = ""
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 44
        End With
    Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
    
haveError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub


'check if a cell has validation
Function CellHasValidation(cell As Range) As Boolean
    Dim vt
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore if error (no validation)
    vt = cell.Validation.Type
    On Error GoTo 0 'stop ignoring errors
    CellHasValidation = Not IsEmpty(vt)
End Function
```

Comment: this works perfectly! Looping didn't even cross my mind. Thank you!